# MSSQL get all SESSION_CONTEXT variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, session-variables, sql-server-2016

How can I get the list of all SESSION_CONTEXT variables or check is any variable was set to session context?

As I know when a variable was not set into session context, SESSION_CONTEXT returns NULL. Since variable can also get NULL value, it can't be exactly determined is a variable was set to context variable or no.

```
EXEC sp_set_session_context 'varnull', null
SELECT SESSION_CONTEXT(N'varnull')   -- returns NULL and variable EXISTS
SELECT SESSION_CONTEXT(N'varnoset')  -- returns NULL and variable DOES NOT EXIST
```

Comment: Session context values cannot be `NULL`; setting them to `NULL` is equivalent to deleting them. If you need to keep track of which variables you've "unset" or "created", you could use some "invalid" value other than `NULL`, like the empty string. Of course, your code needs to be aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

```
exec sp_set_session_context @key, null
```

The statement above really deletes entry with @key from **SESSION_CONTEXT** and decrease **entries_count** in **SESSION_CONTEXT**. Overall memory usage and entries count can be monitored with

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_memory_cache_counters WHERE type = 'CACHESTORE_SESSION_CONTEXT';
```

I think in the current version of SQL Server it is not possible to get a list of entires keys of SESSION_CONTEXT

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have also suspected that this info can't be get from MSSQL